# Laravel whereNull only if the value NULL is selected

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need a filtration by a key *bank* which can have either values like 1,2,3... but also NULL if not set. There's an `select` tag with these options including NULL as the first option and now for example, if the options NULL and 2 are selected I need to filter only those of which *bank* is not set (NULL) or is set to 2.

```
public function scopeFilter($query, $params) {
    $query->when(request('query.status', [10, 11]), function ($query, $params) {
            return $query->whereIn('status', $params);
    });

    $query->when(request('query.bank'), function ($query, $params) {
        return $query->whereIn('bank', $params)->orWhereNull('bank');
    });

    return $query;
}
```

This always returns Posts of which *bank* isn't set (is NULL).. I need to show these only if NULL option is selected by `select` tag. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the solution. Now the `orWhereNull` doesn't affect other clauses. Could it be more simplified, please?

```
$query->when(request('query.bank'), function ($query, $params) {
    return $query->where(function ($query) use ($params) {
        $query->whereIn('bank', $params);

        if (in_array(null, $params)) {
            $query->orWhereNull('bank');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually check whether the `null` is passed in the `$params` and only then add the condition.

```
$query->when(request('query.bank'), function ($query, $params) {
    $query->where(function($query) use ($params) {
        $query->whereIn('bank', $params);
        if (in_array(null, $params)) {
             $query->orWhereNull('bank');
        }
        return $query;
    });
    return $query;
});
```

Comment: Looks better, but I noticed that `orWhereNull` ignores previous `when` (_status_ condition). I updated my code above, now it's full (one more `when` was added). Please look at it.

Comment: I've added a `where` around the two conditions that need to be `OR`. If you don't do that, then indeed the `orWhereNull` will be used over the entire query and not just this section.

Comment: Great, thanks and what in case there will be more conditions like _status_? Probably in foreseeable future there will be more of them. Thanks!